# Loop doesn't work with multiprocessing and sleep

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

I know that this question has already been ask. But I can't an answer wich works like a charm...

So I have a process where I execute a while loop. But it doesn't loop. It do one turn and after... I don't know. This my loop :

```
import os
import time
import signal
import getdata
import twitter
import multiprocessing

collector = getdata.collectData(0)  # Pour récupérer les données
botter = twitter.twitter()  # Pour tweeter


def data_update_loop():
    while True:
        print 'Tour de boucle!'
        start = time.time()  # On calcule le temps d'éxecution

        global collector, botter

        collector.write_data()
        botter.hourly_message()

        done = time.time()  # On stope le chrono

        # On s'assure que le programme attende bien une demie-heure
        time.sleep(1800 - (done - start))

def abort():
    f = open('RUNNING.txt', 'r')
    process = f.readline()
    process = filter(None, process.split(","))

    try:
        for p in process:
            os.kill(int(p), signal.SIGQUIT)
    finally:
        f.close()
        os.remove('RUNNING.txt')


def main():
    if not os.path.isfile('RUNNING.txt'):
        f = open('RUNNING.txt', 'w+')

        data_update = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_update_loop)

        data_update.start()

        # On écrit les PIDs pour pouvoir fermer les process après
        f.write('{},{}'.format(data_update.pid, mentions_update.pid))
        f.close()

        choice = raw_input('Press X to abort all processes: ')
        if choice.upper() == 'X':
            abort()

    else:
        print 'Please restart the programm.'
        os.remove('RUNNING.txt')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        abort()
```

Can you explain me why? I know that it's something about the CPU...
Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

I didn't analyse your program deeply, but the reason is the main process doesn't wait for its child to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I thought it worked, but nope, it still doesn't work...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import time
import signal
import getdata
import twitter
import multiprocessing

collector = getdata.collectData(0)  # Pour récupérer les données
botter = twitter.twitter()  # Pour tweeter


def data_update_loop():
    while True:
        start = time.time()  # On calcule le temps d'éxecution

        global collector, botter

        collector.write_data()
        botter.hourly_message()

        done = time.time()  # On stope le chrono

        # On s'assure que le programme attende bien une demie-heure
        time.sleep(1800 - (done - start))


def mentions_update_loop():
    global botter
    botter.mentions()


def abort():
    f = open('RUNNING.txt', 'r')
    process = f.readline()
    process = filter(None, process.split(","))

    try:
        for p in process:
            os.kill(int(p), signal.SIGQUIT)
    finally:
        f.close()
        os.remove('RUNNING.txt')


def main():
    if not os.path.isfile('RUNNING.txt'):
        print 'Press ctrl + c to abort all processes.'

        f = open('RUNNING.txt', 'w+')

        data_update = multiprocessing.Process(target=data_update_loop)
        mentions_update = multiprocessing.Process(target=mentions_update_loop)

        data_update.start()
        mentions_update.start()

        # On écrit les PIDs pour pouvoir fermer les process après
        f.write('{},{}'.format(data_update.pid, mentions_update.pid))
        f.close()

    else:
        print 'Please restart the programm.'
        os.remove('RUNNING.txt')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        abort()
```

As you said, I updated my main() function and it doesn't do anything after the starting of the processes...

Thanks for helping!